# Can't run code in Android studio due to VT-x disabled

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**When i try to run my code in android studio i got an error"Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. VT-x is disabled in BIOS.  Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings (refer to documentation for your computer)." . I did every thing i could but i couldn't fix it . Can anybody tell me in detail how**

Comment: Not without knowing more about your BIOS. You need to reboot your computer, and look for the "Setup" key. It's before your Operating System boots.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your processor supports virtualization technology
Intel processors from i3 supports it.
If your processor is above i3, then Go to BIOS and look for an option named VTx or virtualization and Enable it...save changes and exit

Now open your web browser and search for HAxm drivers and install the latest one.
You should be good

P.S: if your processor is below i3, you cannot run avd

Answer (score 0):

If your computer does not support Virtualization, there are emulators that don't require it. I know one that many people use is Genymotion.

Alternatively, of course, you can test on a physical device.

Comment: Genymotion user virtualbbox to emulate which requires virtualization.You can use bluestacks